# Can't Workbook.Open an XLS File Type?

Tags: excel, vba

Stuck on this one. I'm creating a 2016 Excel macro that (will hopefully) loop through all .xls files in a folder and make some formatting changes, however my workbook.open doesn't open the .xls file. It seems like it just glances right over it? I've unchecked all the boxes in the Trust Centre, so why won't this open the .xls file in my VBA code? Anything else I can try? It works if the file is of .xlsx format, but not .xls for some reason. Relevant section of code is below. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As requested, I'm going to try and get a bit more technical here. I've added a full script here (without any of the formatting stuff that it does) for someone to troubleshoot with me.

What's interesting to note here is:

Even though I have it set to only look for `.xls` file types in the loop, for some reason it carries out all of my formatting commands in the current macro `.xlsm` workbook, which it shouldn't. So as a workaround, I also had included the line

```
' Start a loop for all .xlsx files in the folder (defined in the last step)
Do While Filename <> "" And Filename <> "Bid_Report_Macro.xlsm" ' This workbook's name
```

to prevent this from happening in the current workbook. I would notice that all my formatting stuff would carry out once I clicked this button, within the same workbook, not the .xls file that it should be opening first. Don't ask me why that happens because I really don't know.

Also, the `.xls` file that I'm trying to open is a `Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)` file. I have unchecked all of the boxes in the Trust Centre regarding blocking the opening of certain file types/file blocking. If I run this same code, but source all `.xlsx` files in a folder instead, it'll work. So I don't know why it's not working for the `.xls` files. When I click my macro button, nothing happens.

I tried to include `CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData` and `CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile` in the open function, but that didn't do anything either.

I've tried the suggestions shown below and they didn't work. I'm assuming it has something to do with my local machine as it's a work computer, but I really don't know where to look and I would like to get this project done.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
Sub Bid_Report_Function()

' Create (but don't define yet) some variables used throughout
Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim EmptyDays As Integer

' Run it in the background.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Directory of this macro that has the other .xls files
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

' A conditional for finding the directory with proper structure
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

' Do this for each xls workbooks in the folder
Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")

' Start a loop for all .xlsx files in the folder (defined in the last step)
Do While Filename <> "" 'And Filename <> "Bid_Report_Macro.xlsm" ' This workbook's name

    ' Open a workbook in the folderPath
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)

    ' Always start on the first worksheet of the opened workbook
    wb.Worksheets(1).Activate

    '......my formatting code is here. Skipping to the end...

    ' Rename the current tab
    wb.ActiveSheet.Name = "RENAMED TAB"


    ' Save as, a copy as a .xls file
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="TEST.xls"

    ' Close but don't save the current workbook to keep it the same
    wb.Close False


' This prevents the macro from doing all of the above endlessly.
Exit_Loop:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Filename = Dir

' Next workbook in the directory
Loop

' Can turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' End program
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note - why the `Filename <> "Bid_Report_Macro.xlsm"`, if you're only looking at `.xls`?

Comment: @BigBen I left that in there because I initially had '(star).xls(star)' as part of my troubleshooting, and didn't want the already open workbook with the macro button in it to be considered in the loop.

Comment: @Matt Wilson I have tried your code and it works fine. I used Excel 2016 and read cell (1) with msgBox.
In cell (1) of the.xls file I wrote test. in the last line, of your code, I added this code MsgBox wb.Worksheets (1) .Cells (1) .Value and I got the "test".
In this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open there is an example. I hope this helps you

Comment: I don't actually see a 'proper' loop to go through files in a folder.

Comment: @Ferdinando Thanks, but it's not working on my end. It will work if it tries to loop through .xlsx files, but not .xls. I think the problem is because that .xls file is of the old 93-97 format, or whatever the years are. And I'm running this on a work machine, so my thinking is that it just automatically chooses to not open .xls files as part of the trust centre, but like I said I checked that section and still nothing. Any other ideas would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Do loop should look more like this:

```
' Start a loop for all .xlsx files in the folder (defined in the last step)
Do While Filename <> ""
    If Filename <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then 'This workbook's name
        ' Open a workbook in the folderPath
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)
        ' Always start on the first worksheet of the opened workbook
        wb.Worksheets(1).Activate
    End If
    'get the next file in the folder which matches the Directory search
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion and thought that maybe that CorruptLoad would help, but it didn't. It's almost like it just glances over the .xls file in the folder, or rather, it doesn't even register that a file is in there. I think it might have something to do with Excel VBA not allowing the 93-97 file format or something like that?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and technical? Instead of saying it 'glances' over etc, what code line? Does it enter an if block? Does it change the value of fileName? What are some technical steps etc

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Although it isn't a great solution, but I got it working by actually defining the full filename of the .xls file I was hoping to use. This isn't great, because it doesn't recognize all of the .xls files in the folder, rendering the loop useless, but for now it works. This is the working code. I will try and get a working loop for it someday. Thanks!

```
' Run it in the background.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Directory of this macro that has the other .xls files
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

' A conditional for finding the directory with proper structure
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

' Do this for each xls workbooks in the folder
Filename = Dir(folderPath & "translate_quote_42666432_v6_all.xls")

' Start a loop for all .xlsx files in the folder (defined in the last step)
Do While Filename <> ""

    ' Open a workbook in the folderPath
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)

    ' Always start on the first worksheet of the opened workbook
    wb.Worksheets(1).Activate
```